# Multiply scipy sparse matrix with a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have the following matrices

```py
a = sp.random(150, 150)
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(150, 20))
```

and I would basically like to implement the following formula

[image]

I can calculate the inner difference like this

```py
diff = (x[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :]) ** 2
diff.shape  # -> (150, 150, 20)

a.shape  # -> (150, 150)
```

I would basically like to broadcast the element-wise multiplication between the scipy sparse matrix and each internal numpy array.

If A was allowed to be dense, then I could simply do

```py
np.einsum("ij,ijk->k", a.toarray(), (x[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :]) ** 2)
```

but A is sparse, and potentially huge, so this isn't an option. Of course, I could just reorder the axes and loop over the `diff` array with a for loop, but is there a faster way using numpy?

As @hpaulj pointed out, the current solution also forms an array of shape `(150, 150, 20)`, which would also immediately lead to problems with memory, so this solution would not be okay either.

Comment: `diff` is 20x bigger than `a` (shapes), and dense.

Comment: Yes, that is true, and this is also a huge problem. I'll update the question with this in mind. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: `einsum`, even when it works, isn't going to improve memory use.  You still calculate the 3d `diff`.  `np.einsum('ij,ijk->k, a.A, diff)` and `np.sum(a.A[:,:,None]*diff), axis=(0,1))` will I think have similar memory uses, equivalent to one or two copies of the 3d `diff` in temporary buffers. (caveat, I don't usually do fine grained memory use tracking, and don't like to hang my machine with potential memory errors.)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I rarely use einsum, and used it here just to demonstrate what I wanted to achieve. Regarding memory, even forming an NxN matrix may be problematic. I was hoping there was a clever numpy trick to compute this equation, but perhaps I'll have to resort to numba or cython.

Comment: `np.einsum` is a function, so all of its arguments are evaluated in full before being passed in.

Comment: Call me dense but I don't understand your notation. `x` is a two-dimensional array, but your equation shows it with only one index.

Comment: I guess you've just elided a _k_ index, but that doesn't help with the clarity of your question.

Comment: What you must actually mean is: `\sigma_k = \sum_i^N \sum_j^N A_{i,j} (x_{i,k} - x_{j,k})^2`

Comment: Yes, sorry, about that! You're completely right. I'll update the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
from numpy.random import default_rng

rand = default_rng(seed=0)

# \sigma_k = \sum_i^N \sum_j^N A_{i,j} (x_{i,k} - x_{j,k})^2

# Dense method
N = 100
x = rand.integers(0, 10, (N, 2))
A = np.clip(rand.integers(0, 100, (N, N)) - 80, a_min=0, a_max=None)
diff = (x[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :])**2
product = np.einsum("ij,ijk->k", A, diff)

# Loop method
s_loop = [0, 0]
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(2):
            s_loop[k] += A[i, j]*(x[i, k] - x[j, k])**2
assert np.allclose(product, s_loop)

# For any i,j, we trivially know whether A_{i,j} is zero, and highly sparse matrices have more zeros
# than nonzeros. Crucially, do not calculate (x_{i,k} - x_{j,k})^2 at all if A_{i,j} is zero.
A_i_nz, A_j_nz = A.nonzero()
diff = (x[A_i_nz, :] - x[A_j_nz, :])**2
s_semidense = A[A_i_nz, A_j_nz].dot(diff)
assert np.allclose(product, s_semidense)

# You can see where this is going:
A_sparse = scipy.sparse.coo_array(A)
diff = (x[A_sparse.row, :] - x[A_sparse.col, :])**2
s_sparse = A_sparse.data.dot(diff)
assert np.allclose(product, s_sparse)
```

Seems reasonably fast; this completes in about a second:

```py
N = 100_000_000
print(f'Big test: initialising a {N}x{N} array')
n_values = 10_000_000
A = scipy.sparse.coo_array(
    (
        rand.integers(0, 100, n_values),
        rand.integers(0, N, (2, n_values)),
    ),
    shape=(N, N),
)
x = rand.integers(0, 100, (N, 2))

print('Big test: calculating')
s = A.data.dot((x[A.row, :] - x[A.col, :])**2)

print(s)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed and does everything I wanted. Very clever!

Answer (score -2):

Try the following code:

```
a = np.random.rand(150, 150)
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(150, 20))
diff = (x[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :]) ** 2
diff.shape  # -> (150, 150, 20)

a.shape  # -> (150, 150)
b = np.einsum("ij,ijk->k", a, (x[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :]) ** 2)
result = b.sum()
```

For sparse matrix the following code can be used:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np
a = sp.random(150, 150)
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(150, 20))
diff = (x[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :]) ** 2
diff.shape  # -> (150, 150, 20)

a.shape  # -> (150, 150)
b = np.einsum("ij,ijk->k", a.toarray(), (x[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :]) ** 2)
result = b.sum()
```

where a is sparse matrix in COO (Coordinate Format) of shape [150,150]

Comment: As I've stated pretty clearly in my question, I require `a` to be sparse. Simply converting it to dense is not an option due to memory constraints.

Comment: Have edited the code for COO (Coordinate Format) based sparse matrix. If you can convert your sparse matrix in COO format than your code for einsum works fine.

Comment: Your "edit" is literally just a copy of my code, which, again, converts the sparse matrix to a dense array via `a.toarray()`. And, no, COO sparse matrices do not work with `np.einsum`.